# HaishinKit RTMPConnection status changes to NetConnection.Connect.Closed when app goes in background

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, rtmp

I'm using `HaishinKit` in order to stream video and audio from the iOS app. I wan't to pause video and continue audio streaming when app goes in background.
The problem is that `HaishinKit.RTMPConnection` status changes to `NetConnection.Connect.Closed` when app goes in background.

It only happens on a physical device. Connection stays alive on a simulator.

How can I keep connection alive when app goes in background?